# Running out of memory when running rake import task in ruby

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am running a task to import around 1 million orders. I am looping through the data to update it to the values on the new database and it is working fine on my local computer with `8 gig` of ram.

However when I upload it to my AWS instance `t2.medium` It will run for the first 500 thousand rows but towards the end, I will start maxing out my memory when it starts actually creating non-existent orders. I am porting a `mysql` database to `postgres`

am I missing something obvious here?

```
require 'mysql2' # or require 'pg'

require 'active_record'

def legacy_database
  @client ||= Mysql2::Client.new(Rails.configuration.database_configuration['legacy_production'])
end

desc "import legacy orders"
task orders: :environment do
  orders = legacy_database.query("SELECT * FROM oc_order")

  # init progressbar
  progressbar = ProgressBar.create(:total => orders.count, :format => "%E, \e[0;34m%t: |%B|\e[0m")

  orders.each do |order|
    if [1, 2, 13, 14].include? order['order_status_id']
      payment_method = "wx"
      if order['paid_by'] == "Alipay"
        payment_method = "ap"
      elsif order['paid_by'] == "UnionPay"
        payment_method = "up"
      end

      user_id = User.where(import_id: order['customer_id']).first
      if user_id
        user_id = user_id.id
      end

        order = Order.create(
          # id: order['order_id'],
          import_id: order['order_id'],
          # user_id: order['customer_id'],
          user_id: user_id,
          receiver_name: order['payment_firstname'],
          receiver_address: order['payment_address_1'],
          created_at: order['date_added'],
          updated_at: order['date_modified'],
          paid_by: payment_method,
          order_num: order['order_id']
        )

      #increment progress bar on each save
      progressbar.increment
    end
  end
end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to handle memory efficiently, you can run mysql query in batches as suggested by **nattfodd**.

There are two ways to achieve it, as per [mysql documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/select.html):

`SELECT * FROM oc_order LIMIT 5,10;`

or

`SELECT * FROM oc_order LIMIT 10 OFFSET 5;`

Both of the queries will return rows 6-15.

You can decide the offset of your choice and run the queries in loop until your orders object is empty.

Let us assume you handle 1000 orders at a time, then you'll have something like this:

```
batch_size = 1000
offset = 0
loop do
  orders = legacy_database.query("SELECT * FROM oc_order LIMIT #{batch_size} OFFSET #{offset}")

  break unless orders.present?

  offset += batch_size

  orders.each do |order|

    ... # your logic of creating new model objects
  end
end
```

It is also advised to run your code in production with proper error handling:

```
begin
  ... # main logic
rescue => e
  ... # handle error
ensure
  ... # ensure 
end
```

Comment: This combined with `(cache_rows: false)` barely using any memory now, sweet

Answer (score 3):

I assume this line `orders = legacy_database.query("SELECT * FROM oc_order")` loads entire table to the memory, which is very ineffective.

You need to iterate over table in batches. In ActiveRecord, there is [find_each](https://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Batches/ClassMethods/find_each) method for that. You may want to implement your own batch querying using `limit` and `offset`, since you don't use ActiveRecord.

Answer (score 1):

Disabling [row caching](https://github.com/brianmario/mysql2#row-caching) while iterating over the orders collection should reduce the memory consumption:

```
orders.each(cache_rows: false) do |order|
```

Answer (score 0):

there is a gem that helps us do this called [activerecord-import](https://github.com/zdennis/activerecord-import).

```
bulk_orders=[]

orders.each do |order|      
   order = Order.new(
          # id: order['order_id'],
          import_id: order['order_id'],
          # user_id: order['customer_id'],
          user_id: user_id,
          receiver_name: order['payment_firstname'],
          receiver_address: order['payment_address_1'],
          created_at: order['date_added'],
          updated_at: order['date_modified'],
          paid_by: payment_method,
          order_num: order['order_id']
        )
end

Order.import bulk_orders, validate: false
```

with a single **INSERT** statement.

Comment: a single insert statement with 1 million records will likly trigger the max packet error within MySQL.