# Existing users failed to login on production after adding devise pepper

Tags: ruby-on-rails, authentication, devise

we have a production database with thousands of users, in the last release, we have added devise pepper for more security.

Now existing users are failed to login to production. but new users which created after release are able to log in.

I think the problem is salt used to encrypt the password before and after release is different.

Is there any way which will allow both users (Users created before pepper integration and Users created after pepper integration) to log in?

Comment: Are you facing this issue to all other users ?

Comment: Yes for all existing users, but not for the new users(sign up), if i update password for old user from console then login work

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check your DEVISE_PEPPER previous token value, if you changed it now then it's fail for existing user. Either you have to reset DEVISE_PEPPER token value to previous one or you have update user's password with the same password throught rails console.

Answer (score 1):

You need to perform update on old user records using something like following script:

```
begin
  c_pool = ActiveRecord::Base.establish_connection # initialize connection pool
  conn = c_pool.connection # create connection object

  # Fetch number of users that were old
  result = conn.execute("SELECT count(*) from users WHERE created_at < '2018-03-12 08:37:46'", )

  count = result.try(:[], 0).to_i

  batch_size = 100
  my_offset = 0

  while (count > 0) do
    users = User.where("created_at < ?", '2018-03-12 08:37:46').limit(batch_size).offset(my_offset)

    break unless users.present? # Exit from loop if no users.

    users.each do |u|
      u.password = u.old_password_field
      u.save # This will update password_digest column of the user.
      count -= 1
    end

    my_offset += batch_size
  end
rescue => e
  Rails.logger.error "#{e.message}"
ensure
  ActiveRecord::Base.clear_active_connections!
end
```

You can modify batch size according to your requirement. Please look my another [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48642854/running-out-of-memory-when-running-rake-import-task-in-ruby/48644619#48644619) which explains why querying in batch is better for better memory management.

You can run the above script using rails runner.